# Updating Django model with OneToOne field yields "Duplicate entry for id"

Tags: python, django

I have a PUT request that should update my Django model with a OneToOne field linking to another model. After running this successfully once, if I try it again, on serialize.save() I get a `(1062), Duplicate entry '1 for key 'linked_model_id'`.

In my models.py:

```
class ModelToUpdate(models.Model)
linked_model = models.OneToOneField(LinkedModel, null=False, on_delete=models.deletion.CASCADE)
other_stuff

class LinkedModel(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(
        Account, null=False, on_delete=models.deletion.CASCADE)
    account_key = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False, choices=CHOICES)

    created_at = created_at_timestamp()
    updated_at = updated_at_timestamp()
    history = HistoricalRecords()
    unsafe_objects = models.Manager()
    objects = HistoryPreservingManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-account_key']
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['account', 'account_key'], name='unique__account__account_key2'),
        ]
```

In my views.py:

```
class ModelToUpdateView(arg):
        def put(self, request):
        linked_model = request.linked_model
        model_to_update = (linked_model.model_to_update if hasattr(linked_model, 'model_to_update')
                    else ModelToUpdate(linked_model=request.linked_model) )
    
        serializer = ModelToUpdateSerializer(model_to_update, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

In serializers.py:

```
class ModelToUpdateSerializer():
    class Meta:
        model = ModelToUpdate
        fields = ['all', 'my', 'fields', 'in', 'the', 'model']
```

This is the same format as other models in the app with `OneToOneField`s that are updating successfully.

The full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 73, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 259, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb._exceptions.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '1' for key 'linked_model_id'")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sentry_sdk/integrations/django/views.py", line 67, in sentry_wrapped_callback
    return callback(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/app/my_api/my_app/views.py", line 840, in put
    serializer.save()
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 200, in save
    self.instance = self.update(self.instance, validated_data)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 983, in update
    instance.save()
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 753, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 790, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 895, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 933, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1254, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1397, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sentry_sdk/integrations/django/__init__.py", line 500, in execute
    return real_execute(self, sql, params)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 73, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 259, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '1' for key 'linked_model_id'")
2021-12-29 21:38:42,482 - ERROR: Internal Server Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 73, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 259, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb._exceptions.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '1' for key 'linked_model_id'")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sentry_sdk/integrations/django/views.py", line 67, in sentry_wrapped_callback
    return callback(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/app/my_api/my_app/views.py", line 840, in put
    serializer.save()
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 200, in save
    self.instance = self.update(self.instance, validated_data)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 983, in update
    instance.save()
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 753, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 790, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 895, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 933, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1254, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1397, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sentry_sdk/integrations/django/__init__.py", line 500, in execute
    return real_execute(self, sql, params)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 73, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/root/.virtualenvs/my_api/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 259, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '1' for key 'linked_model_id'")
```

And the output of `show create table`:

```
| linkedmodel | CREATE TABLE `linkedmodel` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cycle_key` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `account_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique__account__key2` (`account_id`,`key`),
  CONSTRAINT `accou_account_id_c07c2047_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`account_id`) REFERENCES `account` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

Comment: Could you show the code of `LinkedModel`?

Comment: @YevgeniyKosmak I updated the original post with it.

Comment: And also a full traceback of your error? It's not clear without it.

Comment: Just updated with the full error @YevgeniyKosmak

Comment: Just noticed the declaration of `linked_model` field: `linked_model = (LinkedModel, null=False, on_delete=models.deletion.CASCADE)` instead of `models.ForeignKey(LinkedModel...`. I hadn't seen such a syntax; could you explain what it means? Or it's just a typo?

Comment: Looks like you have some strange DB constraint. Could you also attach a `SHOW CREATE TABLE linked_model` output?

Comment: Sorry, yes that is a typo @YevgeniyKosmak . I updated above, but it's `linked_model = models.OneToOneField(etc etc)`.

Comment: And put the table output in the post since it was too long for a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was pretty simple. It just needed a `related_name` on `LinkedModel`:

```
class LinkedModel(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(
        Account, related_name="linked_model", null=False, on_delete=models.deletion.CASCADE)
```